# CSS/Less Get sibling placed immediately after element excluding/ignoring certain class?

Tags: css, less

So I have something like this:

```
<div class="box visible"></div>
<div class="box hide"></div>
<div class="box hide"></div>
<div class="box hide"></div>
<div class="box foo"></div>
```

I want to target "box foo" only if "box" has the class visible. I have tried

```
.box.visible + .foo //Does not work due to the hidden boxes in between
```

and

```
.box.visible ~ .foo //There may be more than one box with the visible class so this does not work
```

without any luck. I was hoping for something like:

```
.box.visible:not(.hide) + .foo
```

would work, but it does not. 
So the question is, is it possible to get the "box foo" placed immediately after the "box visible" excluding the elements in between?

**EDIT:** It's not garanteed that there is any box with the hide class

**EDIT2** There may be more than one box.foo. I only want to target the first box.foo after the box.visible

Comment: Are each `.foo` with a `.visible`, `.hide` or `.foo` class or are there also elements with only the class `.foo`? If yes, what should happen to `.box.visible + .box.hide + .box + .box.foo `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, if no one has any better solution, I'll guess I'll go with this (and hopefully not target any box.foo I'm not suppose to):

```
.box.visible + .box.foo, //If there is no box.hide 
.box.visible ~ .box.hide + .box.foo
```

**Edit**: This seems to work https://jsfiddle.net/0zamaok0/

Comment: Shouldnt it be `.box.visible ~ .box + .box.foo ` ?? cos you mentioned its not garanteed that there is any box with the hide class. ?

Comment: You still need to un-style / reset styles on second, third, etc `.foo` (see my answer for that)

Comment: There is acutally not garanteed there is any box elements in between at all

Comment: Seeing your fiddle where 2 `.foo` are selected, I understand that in your 2nd edit `I only want to target the first box.foo after the box.visible` => you meant "_each_ first box.foo after (…)" ?

Comment: Yes,  first box.foo after each box.visible

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parent of the `.box` class

For eg:

```
<div class="box-parent">
    <div class="box visible"></div>
    <div class="box hide"></div>
    <div class="box hide"></div>
    <div class="box hide"></div>
    <div class="box foo"></div>
</div>
```

and use the following css:

```
.box-parent > .box{
    display:none;
}

.box-parent > .box.visible,.box-parent > .box.foo{
    display:block;
}
```

This should place the `.foo` after `.visible` ignoring all other `.box`

Also to hide the whole `div` you can always manipulate the `box-parent` div.

```
<div class="box-parent hidden">
</div>

.hidden{
    display:hidden;
}
```

Comment: But this will target the .box.foo even if there is no box.visible, would it not?

Comment: Yes it would..!! Maybe u can manipulate the `box-parent` class and add a `hidden` class to it when the whole thing isnt needed

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS selector means we need to chage Html structure if you don't have option to change structure go with following approach 
Jquery

$( ".box.visible" ).siblings('.box.foo:first').css( "background-color", "red" );

Comment: There may be more than one box.foo, I only want to target the first one after the box.visible.

Answer (score 0):

Summarize after your second edit:

- you want to style `.foo` if following `.visible` (as a general sibling, not necessarily immediately following)
- only for the first `.foo`
- I assume you can't have both `.hide` and `.visible` on the same element (otherwise you should add a `:not(.hide)`)

CSS:

```
// do something with all `.foo` following `.visible`
// todo (see following rule): we only want it for the first one
.box.visible ~ .box.foo {
  // something
}

// override for the second, third, etc ones
.box.foo ~ .box.foo {
  // do the opposite of "something" or reset to initial styles
}
```